# Ruby GSL on OS X

Tags: ruby

I am trying to install Ruby GSL on OS X 10.9. I am using Ruby 2.0.0 installed using RVM. According to its [site](http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/), I need GSL installed first. With that, I used Homebrew to install GSL (`brew install gsl`). Next, I did `gem install gsl`, but was given this error message:

```
compiling fft.c
fft.c:270:60: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  for (i = 0; i < table->nf; i++) gsl_vector_int_set(v, i, table->factor[i]);
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fft.c:614:18: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  shape[0] = n;
           ~ ^
fft.c:706:18: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  shape[0] = n;
           ~ ^
fft.c:773:18: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  shape[0] = n;
           ~ ^
fft.c:910:48: error: use of undeclared identifier 'forward'
  rb_define_const(mgsl_fft, "Forward", INT2FIX(forward));
                                           ^
/Users/yihangho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:241:45: note: expanded from macro 'INT2FIX'
#define INT2FIX(i) ((VALUE)(((SIGNED_VALUE)(i))<<1 | FIXNUM_FLAG))
                                        ^
fft.c:911:48: error: use of undeclared identifier 'forward'
  rb_define_const(mgsl_fft, "FORWARD", INT2FIX(forward));
                                           ^
/Users/yihangho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:241:45: note: expanded from macro 'INT2FIX'
#define INT2FIX(i) ((VALUE)(((SIGNED_VALUE)(i))<<1 | FIXNUM_FLAG))
                                        ^
fft.c:912:49: error: use of undeclared identifier 'backward'
  rb_define_const(mgsl_fft, "Backward", INT2FIX(backward));
                                            ^
/Users/yihangho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:241:45: note: expanded from macro 'INT2FIX'
#define INT2FIX(i) ((VALUE)(((SIGNED_VALUE)(i))<<1 | FIXNUM_FLAG))
                                        ^
fft.c:913:49: error: use of undeclared identifier 'backward'
  rb_define_const(mgsl_fft, "BACKWARD", INT2FIX(backward));
                                            ^
/Users/yihangho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:241:45: note: expanded from macro 'INT2FIX'
#define INT2FIX(i) ((VALUE)(((SIGNED_VALUE)(i))<<1 | FIXNUM_FLAG))
                                        ^
4 warnings and 4 errors generated.
make: *** [fft.o] Error 1
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of GSL no longer include the enums `backward` and `forward`, replacing them with `gsl_fft_forward` and `gsl_fft_backward`, and `gsl_wavelet_forward` and `gsl_wavelet_backward`.

Try applying this patch, which replaces the old enums with the new: https://github.com/mvz/rb-gsl-nmatrix/commit/fe7643cd3026690f7de527b2a220c24330a85018